# Can 'edit_form_after_editor' messages be varied for specific pages?

Tags: customization

I use edit-screen hooks (https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/01/more-hooks-on-the-edit-screen/)to display messages on the new/edit admin page for posts and pages.

Example:

```
function add_screen_message() {
$screen = get_current_screen();
if($screen->post_type=='page' && $screen->id=='page') {
echo "<p class=\"edit-message\">Custom message here.</p>";}
add_action('edit_form_after_editor', 'add_screen_message');
```

Can this be modified to display a specific message according to page id/name/slug, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The edit_form_after_editor action delivers a (WP_Post) Post object as a parameter if you initiate the add_action the right way. After your function name you can set the priority and amount of accepted arguments ([read more here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)).

```
function add_screen_message($post) {
    if($post->post_type=='page') {
        echo "<p class=\"edit-message\">Custom message here.</p>";
    }
}
add_action('edit_form_after_editor', 'add_screen_message', 10, 1);
```

The example above echoes your custom message below the edit form if the post that is edited is of the post type "page".

I can recommend the site [Hookr.io](http://hookr.io/actions/edit_form_after_editor/) for great examples of how to use hooks and filters in WordPress. Hope it helps you moving on with your project.

Comment: ...thanks. What I'm trying to do though, is vary the message for a specific page - by using the id/name/slug of that page.

Comment: In that case all you have to do is to change the conditional function
if($post->post_type=='page') to use post_name for slug och ID for the post id.

Comment: thanks. I might be misunderstanding, but I know how to modify that for a specific CPT, but not for a specific page.

Comment: The full code should be:
`function add_screen_message($post) {
    if($post->post_name=='my-page') {
        echo "<p class=\"edit-message\">Custom message here.</p>";
    }
}
add_action('edit_form_after_editor', 'add_screen_message', 10, 1);`